# How to Import Existing Project into New Project in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-studio-express

I am newer to Windows Phone 7. I Installed Windows Phone 7 2010 Express and Working with in it.

I was create one Windows Phone 7 Project With name of that project is SampleDemo. Now i have XAP file on that name.  But Now i want to Change that XAP file into Name is "Care". Also i want to change the Project name also into "Care".

How to change this?

If i create new Project with the name is "Care" means, How to import that my old project "SampleDemo" into that hnew project like ecclipse?

Please anyone tell step by step procedure to do this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to create a new project and then move everything over. Just rename the existing project.
You can rename the XAP file by editing the projects properties.